# Let $S$ be the sum of all the real coefficients of the expansion of $(1+ix)^{2020}$. What is $\log_{2}|S|$?

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms, binomial-theorem

I know $1$ works for $x$ so far, and have been trying to see if any others work, but haven't been able to get beyond that.

Any ideas? Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: The real part is a polynomial, which at $x=1$ is the sum of its coefficients.

Comment: Evaluating at 1 is potentially unhelpful -- if there are complex coefficients that are not purely imaginary. The OP should start by determining if this is the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So let $X+iY = (1+i)^{2020}$. Note that on the one hand,
$$X+iY = (1+i)^{2020} = \sum_{j=0}^{2020} a_ji^j$$ where $$a_j ={{2020}\choose j}$$ for each such $j$, and thus in particular each $a_j$ is real. Thus from this it follows that
$$X=\sum_{k=0}^{1010} a_{2k}(-1)^k.$$  Also note that, on the other hand, the RHS of this equation immediately above is precisely $S$. Thus,
$$|S| = |X|.$$

However, $$(1+i)^{2020} = ((1+i)^4)^{505}$$ $$=(-4)^{505}.$$ Thus, $X=(-4)^{505}$ and so $|S|=|X| =|4^{505}|$. Taking logs gives $\log_2 |S| =1010$.

Comment: The OP's question asked for the sum of the real coefficients, while this gives the sum of the real parts of *all* coefficients. This is not a big deal since it can be easily shown that all coefficients are either purely real or purely imaginary, but it should be mentioned.

Comment: @Andrew Poelstra, the sum of the real parts of all coefficients *is* the sum of the real coefficients though.

Comment: in this case yes, but not in general -- e.g. the polynomial $x^2 + (1 + i)x + 1$ does not have this property. My point is just that a correct answer needs to mention (and justify) this fact.